# Problems in the measurement of a website in page speed

Tags: pagespeed

Good day. I hace a query, do you know why when doing the analysis of the website wiht page speed, instead of indicating a score by attribute, it gives me a question mark (?)? has it happened to you? how is it solved?

Thanks

[image]

I did the test in incognito mode and it didn't work, I cleared the cookies and browsing history and it didn't work either. I also use Lighthouse, however I would like to obtain results not from the laboratory but from the field, that is why I am interested in using page speed.